# connect raw mf4 data with dbc - asammdf

Tags: python, mdf, asammdf

i am quite new to python. for my masterthesis i need to extract some signales of a mf4 data using asammdf. i've only got the raw mf4 data and da dbc. how can i connect the mf4 data with the dbc and save the required signales in a variable or array.
I've already tried something like that:

```
import mdfreader
import os
import asammdf 
channel_list=['ENSTO_AVL_I', 'ENSTO_AVL_U', 'ENSTO_AVL_TEMP','ENSTO_AVL_SOC']
dir_dbc = r'G:\TS-S2\Studenten\S21\Florian Greimel\Masterarbeit\Data_mf4'
dir_mdfs = r'G:\TS-S2\Studenten\S21\Florian Greimel\Masterarbeit\Data_mf4\MF4_mitDBC'
srcdir = dir_mdfs
dbc = os.path.join(dir_dbc, '20180829_SP2021_Infra_CAN.dbc')
for filename in os.listdir(srcdir):
    print(filename)
    if filename.lower().endswith('.mf4'):
        dat = asammdf.MDF4(os.path.join(srcdir,filename))
        sig = dat.get_can_signal('ENSTO_AVL_SOC',(os.path.join(dir_dbc, '20180829_SP2021_Infra_CAN.dbc'))
```

thanks a lot, mob

Answer (score 0):

you should only use the MDF class (contains the MDF3 or MDF4 methods plus some extra methods on top) . With it you can use the `extract_can_logging` https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.extract_can_logging